# Why am I unable to login to Dashboard after adding myself to admin via phpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

So I have added myself as an admin via following the instructions on this site:

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-an-admin-user-to-the-wordpress-database-via-mysql/

I have done this before and it has worked. When I go into the dashboard and add the creds as I inputted them via phpMyAdmin according to the steps in the URL above, I get an error message saying the username and/or password is incorrect. When I try to email myself a password reset, it says the email address is not recognized.

I go back into phpMyAdmin and all the info is there under wp_users and wp_usermeta. What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For several years already, WordPress does not use md5 to encrypt passwords. Instead, Portable PHP password hashing framework is used.

That is why described method doesn't work anymore.

Comment: KAGG, would you mind pointing me in the direction, where I can educate myself more on this. Obviously I need it and thank you.

Comment: You can try to use some Portable PHP password hashing framework generator on the web (for example http://tools.k2an.com/?page=wordpress), but I am sure if it will work properly. If you have access to ftp, you can create new admin by inserting several lines of code into functions.php